# XPath format required on namespace node

Tags: xpath

Can someone please show me the XPath format i should use to retrieve the 2nd txnDetail node's billAmount ?

I am expecting value 10.00 but i have issues with the namespace and "a:" and XPath fails to retrieve the correct value.

```
<TransactionRsp xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <avlBal>818.00</avlBal>
   <blkAmt>0.00</blkAmt>
   <cardID>2561683577196298</cardID>
   <currBill>GBP</currBill>
   <endBal>390.00</endBal>
   <logDateTime>2013-04-30T12:17:20.4249292Z</logDateTime>
   <msgID>121719721</msgID>
   <rspCode>000</rspCode>
   <startBal>400.00</startBal>
   <txnDetail xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CoreModels">
      <a:txnDetail>
         <a:billAmount>400.00</a:billAmount>
         <a:billConvRate>0.00</a:billConvRate>
         <a:blkAmount>0.00</a:blkAmount>
         <a:debOrCred>1</a:debOrCred>
         <a:itemID>2278</a:itemID>
         <a:itemType>6</a:itemType>
         <a:txnAmount>0.00</a:txnAmount>
         <a:txnCurrency/>
         <a:txnDateTime>2012-02-23T14:35:45</a:txnDateTime>
         <a:txnDescription></a:txnDescription>
      </a:txnDetail>
      <a:txnDetail>
         <a:billAmount>10.00</a:billAmount>
         <a:billConvRate>0.00</a:billConvRate>
         <a:blkAmount>0.00</a:blkAmount>
         <a:debOrCred>0</a:debOrCred>
         <a:itemID>3058</a:itemID>
         <a:itemType>5</a:itemType>
         <a:txnAmount>0.00</a:txnAmount>
         <a:txnCurrency/>
         <a:txnDateTime>2012-07-30T12:22:14</a:txnDateTime>
         <a:txnDescription>Fee: Card Issue</a:txnDescription>
      </a:txnDetail>
   </txnDetail>
</TransactionRsp>
```

Comment: Are you using any programming language in particular to work on this or simple plain XPath?

Comment: Simple plain XPath.  There is no way of registering namespace in IDE i am using for this

Answer (score 0):

It's:

```
//TransactionRsp/txnDetail/a:txnDetail[2]
```

However, depending on your programming language you might have to register the `a` namespace. The document might have a default namespace as well. (Don't expect that the xml you've posted is the whole document)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to pull the relevant data using the following XPath:
/TransactionRsp/txnDetail/*[local-name()='txnDetail'][2]/*[local-name()='billAmount']

Now I need to know how to filter out only txnDetail with an itemType = 6 ??

Any thoughts ?